# help me to find the triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Use cylindrical coordinates to calculate [image]
for the given function and region:

[image]

I found that the limits are for $x$ $0$ to $2\pi$     $r$ $0$ to $5$    and $z$ from $r^2$ to $25$ and the integration function $zr$. I got this as the final answer and it is wrong $7526.73$

Comment: What you said sounds right, you must have taken the integral incorrectly.

Comment: *Help me to find the triple integral* - Sure! Just tell us where you last saw her, and we'll help you search for it! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this could also give you required volume.
$$\int_{0}^{25} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{z}}  rzdrd\theta dz$$

Answer (score 1):

In cylindrical coordinates, $dV = rd\phi drdz$.  Like you said, the region is really just $r^2 \leq z \leq 25$.  Which means that either $r$ ranges from $0$ to $5$ and $z$ ranges from $r^2$ to $25$ or $z$ ranges from $0$ to $25$ and $r$ ranges from $0$ to $\sqrt{z}$.  In either case, $\phi$ ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$.

So the two possible integrals would be:

$$
\int\limits_0^5 rdr \int\limits_{r^2}^{25}zdz\int\limits_0^{2\pi}d\phi = \int\limits_0^{25}zdz\int\limits_0^{\sqrt{z}}rdr\int\limits_0^{2\pi}d\phi
$$

So you can just take out the $2\pi$ from the $\phi$ integral in both cases (and technically that integral could be anywhere).  Here is both ways (we better get the same result both ways):

\begin{align*}
S =& 2\pi\int\limits_0^5 rdr \int\limits_{r^2}^{25}zdz = 2\pi\int\limits_0^5 rdr\left.\left(\frac{z^2}{2}\right)\right|_{r^2}^{25} \\
S=& \pi\int\limits_0^5 r\left(25^2 - r^4\right)dr = \pi\left.\left(25^2\frac{r^2}{2} - \frac{r^6}{6}\right)\right|_0^5 \\
S=& \pi\left(5^4\frac{5^2}{2} - \frac{5^6}{6}\right) = 5^6\pi\left(\frac{3}{6} - \frac{1}{6}\right) = \frac{5^6}{3}\pi \\
S=& \frac{15,625}{3}\pi \approx 16,362.461
\end{align*}

or

\begin{align*}
S=& 2\pi\int\limits_0^{25}zdz\int\limits_0^{\sqrt{z}}rdr = 2\pi\int\limits_0^{25}zdz\left.\left(\frac{r^2}{2}\right)\right|_0^{\sqrt{z}} \\
S=& \pi\int\limits_0^{25}z^2dz = \pi\left.\left(\frac{z^3}{3}\right)\right|_0^{25} = \frac{25^3}{3}\pi = \frac{5^6}{3}\pi
\end{align*}

So we get the same result both ways (again, we better!).